# Not sure about ComponentMeasurements MaxPerimeterDistance

Tags: image-processing

I don't understand what actualy `MaxPerimeterDistance` in `ComponentMeasurements` measures.

For example:
62x16 (white area) [image]
 returns 1, but for 34x32 (minimal bounding box around white area) [image] returns 13.8924

Comment: This appears to be a bug - the result for the first image is incorrect. Try using `SetOptions[DistanceTransform, Padding -> 0]` and recompute.

Comment: Tank you very much. You are right. Now returns `8.` .

Answer (score 1):

following worked for me:

```
ComponentMeasurements[, CornerNeighbors->False]
```

whereas this did not help:

```
SetOptions[DistanceTransform, Padding -> 0]
```